# flutter app is unable to ineract with firebase cloud database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have set my firebase cloud database rule to default

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

but while my flutter app tries to interact with it, this error occurs

> Error performing get, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

means you are disallowing both read and write from and to firestore, you can change the rules to the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read : if true; 
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to read but not write to the database, or you can use the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 9, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

Use the above rules just for testing, check here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure